# How do I delete closed web parts from a page?

Tags: 2007, web-part, performance

Due to a performance issue, I closed a few web parts that were on the page, however I now would like to delete those permanently.

How do I delete closed web parts from a SharePoint page permanently?

Comment: By the way, closing a web part does NOT help performance. My first SharePoint gig, we had a custom Web Part that did a SQL pull and took 5 - 10 seconds to run. I found five closed web parts on the home page, each one was still running in the background even though they were closed. I wish Microsoft would remove this "Close feature", it's the most misleading thing I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These screenshots are from 2003 but its much the same process with 2007/10

[Deleting closed a web part from a web part page in SharePoint](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/reminder/reminder-manual?p=faq/deleteingawebpart/deletingawebpart.htm)

Answer (score 5):

You need to get into the webpart maintainance page , you need to append ?contents=1 where the webpart is hosted e.g

http://server/sites/site/default.aspx?contents=1

Try deleting from there

Answer (score 2):

You can also delete them using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

- Click Site Actions|Edit Page.
- Click "Add a Web Part" on any Web Part Zone.
- From the Add Web Parts dialog, click "Advanced Web Part Gallery and Options".
- From the Add Web Parts panel on the right-hand side of the page, click
   "Closed Web Parts (*some number higher than zero*)".
- Select the first closed Web Part, and click "Add" to add it back to the page.
- From the title bar of your resurrected Web Part, click Edit|Delete and click "OK".
- Repeat previous two steps until "Closed Web Parts" reads zero.

This is a lot faster than going back and forth to the Maintenance Page.

Comment: This is my last resort option because it's tedious - you have to add the web part back to the page before you can delete it, and you can only add one web part at a time (for 2007 anyway). Plus, when you're using this method you have the possibility of confusing the users if they access the page while you're doing this. It does the job though when everything else fails for one reason or another.